# Can Google Maps API v.3 work for Mars?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sql-server-mars

I am playing with writing a little javascript solution that would take place on mars. I would love to have the output result in a google map of a lat and long on Mars. Any thoughts? **Can the following concept BE called for a location on the red planet?**

```
`map = new google.maps.Map();`
```

I see stuff in the API that indicates this at lease WAS doable in v.2, but I don't know if that survived, and can't seem to scare anything relevant up to tell me if this is a possibility or a dead end.

For Earth, this looks straight forward enough.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

 var markerTest = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerTest,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Here's an Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/chakra5/qx3r12xk/

Many thanks in advance for any and all brainstorming.

Comment: There is an example of a map of the Moon [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image).  So yes it is possible.

Comment: http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/planetary-maptypes/planetary-maptypes.html (see Mars types)

Comment: Thanks for your response geocodezip! This is promising, and I'll poke it a little to see if it does what I'm after. Much appreciated!

Comment: update: this rocked. I'm off and running. Thank you!